# Does Chaos Storm silence 0.5 seconds constantly?

Tags: league-of-legends

As Viktor, if any champion is below the cloud, will it be constantly silenced until the target gets out of the cloud, or it will silence just 0.5 seconds?

I ask this because the duration IMO is really low and therefore almost useless if it's a one-time silence...

Comment: think of it as a disrupt for channeling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When initially cast, [Chaos Storm](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Viktor#Chaos_Storm) silences enemy champions within its radius for 0.5 seconds. If the storm was cast directly on an enemy champion it will continue to follow that champion and deal damage for its full duration (7 seconds), or can be redirected by pressing (R) again on a new target, but it will not silence any additional targets during that time.

While the short silences may not seem very useful as a method of preventing enemy champions from casting spells, it's *very* useful for stopping channeled spells such as Katarina's [Death Lotus](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Katarina#Death_Lotus) or Galio's [Idol of Durand](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Galio#Idol_of_Durand).

Answer (score 0):

Viktor's chaos storm silence is certainly not almost useless, in fact it is extremely useful for not only cancelling abilities as RovingBlade already mentioned, but it makes viktor's burst potential higher as he can hit his laser whilst they are silenced without them being able to react. Note that it is not incredibly easy to get close to carries to burst.

What i would like to add is that in the proposed rework for viktor, the silence is being removed from his ultimate.